# Inccorect display of article and section

Tags: html, css

So, i'm making a website as a school assigment, and i wanted to make a gallery of images on one of the pages. The problem is that the article and section won't display correctly. The images display under the header, but the article and section won't display at all (they actually do display, but only because of the set padding of 50px on the section). Is there a way i can make them adjust to the pictures somehow? Because i thought this would work, but it does not. Any help is well appreciated!

here's the CSS

```
  body {
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #111;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

article {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

article header {
  background: #51A0C4;
  padding: 1px; 
}

section {
  width: 75%;
  background: white;
  border: 0px solid;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #51A0C4;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
```

and here's the HTML part

```
<body>
<nav> "navigation"
</nav
<article>                                                                                    
  <header><h1>gallery</h1>                                                                         
  </header>                                                                                              
  <section>                                                                 
    <div class="gallery">                                                                                                                 
      <a target="_blank" href="img/1.png">                                                                                                                                 
        <img src="img/1.png"></a>                                                                                                               
      <div class="desc">"description"                                                                                                                                       
      </div>                                                                                           
    </div>
</section>
</article>
<div class='footer'> "footer"
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: incorrect closing. </nav

Comment: Just a curiosity, if you're going to use html5 tags such as: `article`, `section`, and `nav`, you may also use `footer`, instead of a `div` with a footer class.